# How to create your own Live Template, using the current line (Intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bukkit, live-templates

I am trying to create my own live template which uses the current line that my cursor is on, but I cannot find the variable for it.

To explain what I mean, IntelliJ has a built-in .sout template which SOUTs the current statement. [image]

[image]

I am trying to find a way to add my own .[extention] that wraps the current code on that line, into a  different statement.

So something like this:

[image]

Will turn into this: [image]

Any ideas on how to get that done properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create postfix completion. Rather than Live template, postfix completion surrounds an expression you’ve just typed.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-postfix-completion.html